# How to use toggle/switch button in preference activity

Tags: android, xml, preference

I looked around but couldn't find a single tutorial that tells me how to use the switchpreference in my preference activity and in my main activity. I want to know how to implement it in my application using sharedpreference. Sample code would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preference.xml:

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="test"
    android:title="Test" />
```

PreferenceActivity:

```
public class TestPrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sample);
    }
}
```

Register the shared preference object for the changes

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            boolean test = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("test", false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Value:" + test);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what does R.string.SWITCH mean? Should I create a string ?

Comment: That is name given to your preference

Comment: `android:key="pref_sync"` given in your xml

Comment: how can I call this in my main activity?

Comment: You can use directly by creating sharedpreferences like
`SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedpref.getString("pref_sync");`

Comment: I want to disable some code from my main activity using the toggle button in the preference setting. How can I do this using this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a comparable issue with another establishment of mine.  I fixed it by using `<SwitchPreference android:key="test" android:title="Test" />`